# iterative regression on increasing rows of training dataset in r

Tags: r

I want to perform 10 linear regression (Boston dataset) on increasing number of rows(The first experiment uses 10% of the training data, the second uses 20%, and so on) from training dataset and Evaluate the results on the test set and plot the results, using as X values the percentage of the training set, and as Y the RSE on the test set. I have just started to learn r coding can somebody please guide me here

```
sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(Boston), size = floor(.70*nrow(Boston)), replace = F)
train <- Boston[sample, ]
test  <- Boston[-sample, ]
#I have the following template
Onetestrse<-rep(0,10)
for(i in 1:10)
Train2=train(1:……….)
Lr1 fit=lm(medv~lstat,…train2)
predictions=…
rss=
rse=
Onetestrse[I]=rse
```

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started.

Always state which non-base R libraries you are using. The `Boston` dataset is part of `MASS` so we need to do `library(MASS)`.

1. Set fixed seed for reproducibility.

   ```
   set.seed(2017);
   ```
2. Construct training and test data.

   ```
   sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(Boston), size = floor(.70*nrow(Boston)), replace = F)
   train <- Boston[sample, ];
   test  <- Boston[-sample, ];
   ```
3. Fit a linear model for different percentages of the full training dataset. We randomly sample `fraction.of.train` of `train`.

   ```
   fraction.of.train <- seq(0.1, 1.0, by = 0.1);
   res <- lapply(fraction.of.train, function(x) {
       df <- train[sample(nrow(train), floor(x * nrow(train))), ];
       fit <- lm(medv ~ lstat, data = df);
       return(fit);
   })
   ```
4. As an example for how to process `res` we can store estimates for the model coefficients in a `data.frame`.

   ```
   df.coef <- data.frame(
       fraction.of.train,
       t(sapply(res, function(x) coef(x))));
   #   fraction.of.train X.Intercept.      lstat
   #1                0.1     34.89899 -1.0582710
   #2                0.2     34.11266 -0.9234659
   #3                0.3     34.27738 -0.9703798
   #4                0.4     35.71255 -1.0257534
   #5                0.5     34.90033 -0.9898475
   #6                0.6     33.40422 -0.9042411
   #7                0.7     34.80059 -0.9905163
   #8                0.8     34.56530 -0.9702517
   #9                0.9     34.51626 -0.9610643
   #10               1.0     34.66880 -0.9752710
   ```

Extracting other fit statistics from `res` is straight-forward, and I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thank you so much. so now I am trying to evaluate the result on test set by using 'predict' function but I need to format (class) of 'res' from (list) to (lm). tried 'res1 <- list(list(res))' but doesnt help

Comment: @elle `res` already contains the `lm` return objects in a `list` (you should confirm that with `lapply(res, class)`). You can operate on the individual `lm` objects using `lapply`/`sapply`, just as I demonstrate when extracting coefficients from every `lm` fit object.